# Javascript - Dúvida sobre escopo Global (Funções)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Opa pessoal.

Estou criando um sistema com PHP, MySQL e Javascript, JQuery, HTML5 e CSS.

Hoje eu tenho um arquivo chamado **function_requires.js** no qual tem várias funções que estão no escopo global... exemplos:

```
window.getCEP = (number) => {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + number + "/json/",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            let logradouro = data.logradouro != "" ? data.logradouro : "";
            $("#account_city").val(data.localidade);
            $("#account_state").val(data.uf);
            $("#account_street").val(logradouro);
        }
    });
}

window.validateMask = () => {
    // Mascara de Celular
    $('input[name=whatsapp]').mask('(00) 00000-0000');

    $('input[name=cpf]').mask('000.000.000-00');

    // Mascara de CEP
    // $('input[name=account_cep]').mask('00000-000');
    $('#account_cep').mask('00000-000');

    $('#account_birthday').mask('0000-00-00');
}
```

Minha dúvida é.

Deixar minhas funções em escopo global é uma boa pratica?